# What does "_" means here?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am learning backbone.js, in it's [tutorial](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/), it has the following code

```
var object = {};
_.extend(object, Backbone.Events);
...
```

I don't understand the "**_**" in the code, what does it means? and what is this "extend"? does it has the same meaning as jQuery.extend ?

Comment: _ is the underscore object. It is defined in underscore.js, a dependency of backbone.js. _.extend is not the same function as $.extend (although I think it does the same thing)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It copies all the Backbone.Events properties over to the object. Extend is a method from the underscore library:
http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#extend

I'd say it's the same as the jQuery method.

Answer (score 23):

From Backbone's own homepage :

> Backbone's only hard dependency is
>   Underscore.js.

`_` is the object created by Underscore.js, in the same way as `$` is the jQuery object

http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#extend as for what `_.extend` does.